# Error in simple shell script prorgam

Tags: bash, syntax

I am new to shell scripting and stuck in some syntax error in a simple program. I read an integer and compare it with some value to display the result
Please tell me how to rectify it.

```
#! /bin/bash

read n
if [ "$n" -le 12 ]
then
 echo "a kid"
elif[ "$n" -lt 18 ]
then
 echo "a teen"
else
 echo "an adult"
fi
```

The error was:

```
./hello.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./hello.sh: line 8: `then'
```

Comment: You missed a space after `elif`. I would recommend using a tool like https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check your scripts–it will give much clearer error messages for issues like this.

Comment: yes,  that was it. Thanks @OllinBoerBohan

Comment: @OllinBoerBohan: Make that an answer please.

Comment: Shellcheck was helpful. ThankU

Answer (score 4):

**You're missing a space between `elif` and `[`**, which causes a parsing error later on.

For future reference, the [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) tool is a good way to diagnose errors like this one.